# How to send multiple images in a Expressjs api get request with sendFIle()

Tags: api, express, mean-stack, sendfile

I'm looking for away to send multiple images in one GET request from an Expressjs server through an api.

I want to create an image gallery of each users uploaded images in a MEAN stack. When images are uploaded using multer, the image information is saved to mongodb, including the userid of whoever uploaded it.

When on angularjs, I want user to have access to any of the images they have previously uploaded. Currently I'm sending one file on a GET request based on user id. Is there anyway of sending multiple files in one json. I'm currently using Expressjs's `res.sendFile`, but haven't found any info about sending multiple back yet.

https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile

Here is my current get request:

```
exports.getUpload = function(req, res) {
    Upload.find({createdby: req.params.Id}).exec(function(err, upload) {
        errorhandle.errorconsole(err, 'file found');
        console.log(upload[0]);
        var options = {
            root: '/usr/src/app/server/public/uploads/images'
        };
        var name = "" + upload[0].storedname +"";
        console.log(name);
        res.sendFile(name, options,function(err) {
            errorhandle.errorconsole(err, 'file sent');
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't with `res.sendFile`. In fact I don't think you can at all. Maybe with [HTTP/2 Server Push](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/2_Server_Push)
, but I'm not sure.

What you can do is send a JSON response with a link to all the images:

```
exports.getUpload = async (req, res) => {
    const uploads = await Upload.find({ createdby: req.params.Id }).exec()
    const response = uploads.map(image => {name: `https://example.com/uploads/images/${image.storedname}`})
    res.json(response)
}
```

Note error handling omitted.